# Dynamically fill some data in android/app/build.gradle (React Native ap)

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, identityserver4, multi-tenant

For my react-native application I am using [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) library.

I need to fill this info in build.gradle file, for android:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      appAuthRedirectScheme: 'io.identityserver.demo'
    ]
  }
}
```

But *appAuthRedirectScheme* can be different for some roles of users. And I need to send this scheme directly from react-native components (when I get that scheme/url from another API).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: FYI, maybe it's helpful to look up how to do it using the underlying library: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android